# What is the best way of getting images located after specific tag in html markup in python/beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find images located passed H1 tag. The markup can be any article on online magazine ([example](http://www.forbes.com/sites/markrogowsky/2013/06/10/apple-wwdc-ios7-to-keep-things-simple/)). 
That means I can't rely on specific containers etc.

My initial idea was to find character position of H1 tag and found images. That would let me determine their position in relation to H1 tag. I can't find a way to get character position of found element with **beautiful soup**, unless I'm missing something.

Whatever approach has to be used to parse html it has to work with ill-formed syntax.

Example:

```
<html>
    <p>some text</p>
    <img src="#" alt="I don't care about this image"/>
    <h1>This is the title</h1>
    <img src="#" alt="This is the first image I want to get"/>
    <p>some more content</p>
    <img src="#" alt="This is the secod image I want to get"/>
</html>
```

Parsing above html would return a list with 2 images located below H1 tag.

UPDATE: I completely rewrote my question to better explain the problem.

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to find images positioned after H1 tag in the order of appearance. Perhaps there's a way to tell beautiful soup to start looking for images after H1 tag? That would do the job.

Comment: @Blender This is for the script trying to find most relevant image in the article. For example: http://www.forbes.com/sites/markrogowsky/2013/06/10/apple-wwdc-ios7-to-keep-things-simple/

Comment: `soup.find(class_='article').find('img')` may be all you need.

Comment: Nope. This doesn't return desired image. This has to work for any given URL that contains H1 tag.

Comment: You're going to have to explain this more if you want any sort of assistance. Your question right now is unanswerable because it's very vague.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question. The solution to get all images after H1 tag would be:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_contents, 'html5lib') # parse html markup
soup_h1 = soup.find('h1') # find H1 tag
soup_imgs = soup_h1.find_all_next('img') # returns a list of img objects
```

Thanks to everyone for help.

Answer (score 0):

[lxml](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) might be an easy fit for this.  This will grab all img tags, but only print ones preceded by an h1 tag.  It does it in order as they appear in the DOM as well.

```
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO

html = """
<body>
<h1>a</h1>
<img src="afterh1-1"/>
<h2>b</h2>
<img src="afterh2"/>
<h1>a</h1>
<img src="afterh1-2"/>
</body>
"""

f = StringIO(html)
tree = etree.parse(f)

for i in tree.xpath('//img'):
    if i.getprevious().tag.lower() == "h1":
        print "Match: %s - %s" % (i.get('src'), i.getprevious().tag)
```

Output:

```
Match: afterh1-1 - h1
Match: afterh1-2 - h1
```

Here's the beautifulsoup version that yields the same output

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<body>
<h1>a</h1>
<img src="afterh1-1"/>
<h2>b</h2>
<img src="afterh2"/>
<h1>a</h1>
<img src="afterh1-2"/>
</body>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for i in soup.find_all('img'):
    if i.previous_sibling.previous_sibling.name == "h1":
        print "Match: %s - %s" % (i.get('src'), i.previous_sibling.previous_sibling.name)
```

Comment: Will lxml work with ill-formed html? I believe beautiful soup does a good job with it.

Comment: They are both based on libxml2 underneath, but beautifulsoup is aimed to solve the ill-formed problems better.  I posted the bs4 equiv in the answer as well.  Cheers

Comment: Thanks, but this will not work with just any document. I rewrote my questions please take a look.

Comment: Just realised that one solution could be to find H1 first and do h1.find_all_next() which will return a list of all parent objects past h1 tag. The only problem is you have to loop though them individually and look for image. Seems not very efficient.